# I need to select routes from route-container div and display it in select options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am working on a website about travel and I need to select routes from 'route-container' div and then display these routes in my both select option. First option is departure and the second one represents arrival city . 
here is my code pan. 
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GXVyqj

```
 <html>
    <head> 
    <style>
    .route-container {
      background-color:grey;
      width:30%;
      margin-top:10px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <select>
        <option value="">Islamabad</option>
        <option value="">Lahore</option>
        <option value="">Karachi</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option value="">Karachi</option>
        <option value="">Lahore</option>
        <option value="">Queta</option>

    </select>
    <div class="container route-container"> 
      <b>Select your Route </b>
      <p>Islamabad-Lahore</p>
      <p>Karachi-Lahore</p>
      <p>Lahore-Queta</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What you have tried in jQuery to do this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ugly as hell but it works. Will be a lot better if you define better selectors and set values for the option elements.

Note: I do event delegation from the `.route-container` div. If your routes are static you can use normal event too.

```js
$('.route-container').on('click', 'p', function() {
  var places = $(this).text().split('-');
  if (places.length === 2) {
    for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
      $($('select')[i]).children('option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === places[i]) {
          $(this).prop('selected', true);
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    console.error('no route found in clicked element');
  }
});
```

```css
.route-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select>
  <option value="">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="">Lahore</option>
  <option value="">Karachi</option>
</select>
<select>
  <option value="">Karachi</option>
  <option value="">Lahore</option>
  <option value="">Queta</option>
</select>
<div class="container route-container">
  <b>Select your Route </b>
  <p>Islamabad-Lahore</p>
  <p>Karachi-Lahore</p>
  <p>Lahore-Queta</p>
</div>
```

This is a more beautiful way but i altered your html a bit.

```js
$('.route-container').on('click', 'p', function() {
  var places = $(this).text().split('-');
  if (places.length === 2) {
    $('#startLocation').val(places[0]);
    $('#endLocation').val(places[1]);
  } else {
    console.error('no route found in clicked element');
  }
});
```

```css
.route-container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="startLocation">
  <option value="Islamabad">Islamabad</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
</select>
<select id="endLocation">
  <option value="Karachi">Karachi</option>
  <option value="Lahore">Lahore</option>
  <option value="Queta">Queta</option>
</select>
<div class="container route-container">
  <b>Select your Route </b>
  <p class=route>Islamabad-Lahore</p>
  <p class=route>Karachi-Lahore</p>
  <p class=route>Lahore-Queta</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort, at least it works for me :)